# How do I plot multiple per-type line graphs in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a bunch of CSV data imported in Excel: tuples are Timestamp, Type, Type Count.
I'd like to plot multiple per-type line graphs but Excel keeps choking on me; can anyone suggest how should I order the columns?

Comment: Ok ok... found it:

1. make pivot out of tuple, timestamp on Row, Type on Column, Count on Value
2. change summarize-by method on value field from - the (brain dead) default - count to sum
3. plot chart as wished

Comment: You should put up your solution as an answer to your own question; other people might find it useful too. :)

Comment: I would but the system said don't have enough points to answer my own question... go figure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make pivot out of tuple, timestamp on Row, Type on Column, Count on Value
2. Change summarize-by method on value field from - the (brain dead) default - count to sum
3. Plot chart as wished